# Access a particular span through an input id

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<span class="e-datewidget e-widget validityDate e-ntouch e-valid">
  <span class="e-in-wrap e-box e-padding">
    <input id="ValidityDate" readonly="readonly">
    <span id="ValidityDate-img" class="e-select" style="display: block;">
        <span class="e-icon e-calendar" aria-label="Select">
        </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

I want apply a `display:none` styling on the span having `class: "e-icon e-calendar"`.

How can I access this span through the input id in `CSS` to set the display:none styling?

Comment: Adjacent sibling combinator to target the span that follows the input, then descendant combinator to target the `.e-icon.e-calendar` inside of that.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#ValidityDate + span > .e-icon.e-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```